# Dividir Projecto QML em Sub-Directorias

Tags: qml

## Tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Dividi um projecto de **QML**, em **diferentes sub-directorias.**
Ao fazer **build**, o IDE **não consegue localizar os ficheiros implementados**, devolvendo o seguinte erro:

```
Starting /Users/macbook/workspace/build-UI_UX_Framework-          Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_clang_64bit-    Debug/UI_UX_Framework.app/Contents/MacOS/UI_UX_Framework...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/_files_qml/instantiationTest.qml:17 Button1 is not a type

/Users/macbook/workspace/build-UI_UX_Framework-  Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_clang_64bit-   Debug/UI_UX_Framework.app/Contents/MacOS/UI_UX_Framework exited with code 0
```

Tentei **mudar opções no ficheiro .Framework.pro**, mas não consegui resolver a questão. agradeço o feedback
Fica aqui uma imagem do projecto.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwPLV.jpg

Comment: no meu caso, esqueci-me de fazer include dos ficheiros, nas respectivas sub-directorias. fica algo desse género:

Comment: import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import "_Buttons/"
import "_MIDIKeyboards/"
import "_StochasticSelectors/"
import "_Sliders/"
import "_imgButtons/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>*esqueci-me de fazer include dos ficheiros, nas respectivas sub-directorias. foi algo do género:*</sub>

```
import QtQuick 2.0 
import QtQuick.Window 2.0 
import "_Buttons/" 
import "_MIDIKeyboards/" 
import "_StochasticSelectors/" 
import "_Sliders/" 
import "_imgButtons/"
```